# Regx to test space alphanumeric text in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

Currently I'm using "(?i)lt[\s]*[\d]+" to converts lt34 or Lt34 or lT34 and lt 34 or Lt 34 or lT 34 to Lt34 and Lt 34 respectively using one regex. 34 is just a numeric value and can be anything but the text "lt" is fix with any casing which should be converted to "Lt"(camel casing using regex).

This is even working for aflt123 by converting it to AFLt123 which is not acceptable it should be AFLT123 in this case. If there is text before lt then there must be at least one space before lt.

Please help to improve the regex which is "(?i)lt[\s]*[\d]+"

Comment: I guess you need `"(?i)\\blt\\s*\\d+"`

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand your question but wouldn't a simple word boundary (`\b`) do the trick? `(?i)\blt\s*\d+`. Besides that, you don't need the square brackets in `[\s]` etc. because `\s` already is a shortcut for a character class.

Comment: Try this `^(?i)lt[\s]*[\d]+`